# How to format this txt file to make it import

Tags: r

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
PXYXYXYXYXYXYXXYXXY 
XYXYXYXYXY 
1.828 
1.44928000 
1.20000000 
XYXYX 
XYXYX 
XYXY 
10096247566 


PXYXYXYXYXZZYXXYXXY 
XYZZYXYXYXY 
1.528 
1.45928000 
1.70000000 
XYXYX 
XYXYX 
XYXY 
10096247566 

.....
```

Every line in each bulk is different datapoints (first line in bulk 1 is the same data type as first line in bulk 2. How do I import this file  in R?

Comment: Regular expressions to replace single new lines with tabs, then import with `fread` or whatever.

Comment: Try `mydata <- readLines(...)`, then `mydata <- matrix(mydata, nrow = 9)`

Comment: @zx8754 more ingenious! But to the person with regex, everything looks like a nail https://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: Thanks guys. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use regular expressions to replace the single new lines with tabs:

   *find: `(?<=.)\n` replace: `\t`*

   https://regex101.com/r/6NlnAp/1
2. Use regular expressions to replace the double new lines with single new lines:

   *find: `\n\n` replace: `\n`*
3. Add a line at the top with headings.

You now have a well formed text file to import with `fread` or `read.csv`.

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate it :)